# TypeError: Input 'serialized' of 'ParseExample' Op has type float32 that does not match expected type of string

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I was developing a CNN neural network for image classification by using estimators in Tensorflow. This error was encountered in the saving process. The following is my code for the saving part:

```
        def serving_input_rec_fn():
            serialized_tf_example = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,
                                                   # shape=[-1, self.num_input[0], self.num_input[1], 1],
                                                   name='input')
            receiver_tensors = {"myInput": serialized_tf_example}
            feature_spec = {"examples": tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[self.num_input[0], self.num_input[1]], dtype=tf.float32)}
            features = tf.parse_example(serialized_tf_example, feature_spec)
            return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(features, receiver_tensors)

        model.export_savedmodel(export_dir, serving_input_rec_fn,
                                     strip_default_attrs=True)
```

The error seems to be that in the serialized_tf_example argument of the tf.parse_example function, it expects the data type to be string. But my input image type is actually float32. How can I solve the problem? In my understanding of the placeholder here, it will serve as the input subgraph with the main graph when the model is exported for serving. Therefore, why is the string type expected for the serialized_tf_example?

Comment: How did you solve the problem?